# GeoToolKit conversion from lat/long to UTM

Tags: coordinate-system, java

What is the proper way to convert lat/longs to a UTM coordinate system using the Java geotoolkit API? I have not worked with GIS software before, so maybe what I am trying to do is not directly possible. I found a few tutorials, but nothing with the full solution.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Here is the solution in case anyone else is interested. UTM is not a single projection, but actually a set of 120 different UTM zones. The zones are divided in 6 deg increments starting at -180 deg longitude, continuing to 180 deg longitude. This creates 60 zones, and since there is a northern and southern zone for each range, the total becomes 120.

> **Update:** As mentioned below, this is a simplification of the UTM standard, and will not be accurate for a few unique regions around Norway.

The next hurdle is then converting the UTM zone to the [EPSG database code](http://reference.mapinfo.com/common/docs/mapxtend-dev-web-none-eng/miaware/doc/guide/xmlapi/coordsys/systems.htm), so it can be retrieved using the geotoolkit API. The code makes it clear how the EPSG code can be reached, once you've figured out the UTM zone.

```
private static int utm_zone( double _long ){
  assert _long > -180.0 && _long < 180.0;
  return (int)(Math.ceil((180 + _long)/6.0));
}

public void asUTMCoordinates( double longitude, double latitude) throws
     MismatchedDimensionException, TransformException {

  Point p = FactoryFinder.getPrimitiveFactory(null).createPoint( new double[] {longitude,latitude} );

  // define base EPSG code value of all UTM zones;
  int epsg_code = 32600;
  // add 100 for all zones in southern hemisphere
  if (this.getLatitudeInDeg() < 0) {
     epsg_code += 100;
  }
  // finally, add zone number to code
  final int zone = utm_zone( longitutde );
  epsg_code += zone;

  MathTransform crs_transform;
  try {
     CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84  = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84; // EPSG:4326
     CoordinateReferenceSystem utm    = CRS.decode("EPSG:"+epsg_code);
     crs_transform = CRS.findMathTransform(wgs84,utm);
  } catch (NoSuchAuthorityCodeException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
  } catch (FactoryException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  DirectPosition p2 = crs_transform.transform( p.getDirectPosition(), null );
  double[] c = p2.getCoordinate();
  System.out.println( String.format("%d, %f, %f", zone, c[0], c[1]) );
}
```

Comment: This approach is fundamentally flawed because there are [non-standard UTM zones](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2561/what-was-the-rationale-for-the-non-standard-utm-zones-near-norway).

Comment: agreed, I forgot to mention that. My data is all outside of the non-standard zones, so this feature was not relevant in my design. Feel free to submit a revised solution.